# How to pass and retrieve JSON function as data via ajax to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm working on shopping cart. Now I need to pass the array of objects added into shopping cart which is stored in localStorage to php page in order to insert into database.

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
```

Above logs out, the following:

```
[{"name":"Banana","price":1.33,"count":5},{"name":"Apple","price":1.22,"count":5},{"name":"Shoe","price":22.33,"count":1}]
```

Now I'm trying to pass this JSON string to a php page called submit_cart.php and retrieve the string in php page correctly, how do I do that? Currently it's sending and receiving empty data.

```
$("#submit-cart").click(function(event){
                console.log("****TEST LOG ***");
                console.log(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
                var data = localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart");
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "json",
                  url: "submit_cart.php",
                  data: data,
                  success: function(data) {
                    console.log("******success******");
                    console.log(data);//this logs []
                  }
                 });
            });
```

In submit_cart.php

```
<?php
$return = $_POST;
$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
$data = json_decode($return["json"], true);

echo json_encode($return["json"]);
  ?>
```

EDITED as suggested answer and it's working now:

```
$("#submit-cart").click(function(event){
                console.log("****TEST LOG ***");
                console.log(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
                var data = localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart");

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "submit_cart.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
            console.log("******success******");
            console.log(data);//this logs []
            }
            });
            });
```

In submit_cart.php

```
<?php
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

print_r($_POST);
  ?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: In the success function of ajax , I get empty data,meaning ajax doesn't send data correctly or php doesn't decode it correctly.

Comment: Put an alert after assigning value to data and see what value you are getting like alert(data);

Comment: Put a `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your PHP script, so you can see what it contains. I am pretty sure doing a `json_encode()` of all of the $_POST array is NOT what you want to do.

Comment: if it is already encoded in json format then why you are using `json_encode($return);`. remove `json_encode($return);` and check

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. You encode the POST superglobal and then decode it again and then echo the JSON equivalent of the same again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the ajax request set the content type to json and on the php side read the json from php://input

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  url: "submit_cart.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("******success******");
    console.log(data);//this logs []
  }
});
```

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
// then use post as usual
```

Comment: Hi Musa, silly question, why do you use `file_get_contents('php://input')` rather than just using `$_POST` as delivered by PHP. I am just interested, not picking holes!

Comment: $_POST is only populated for certain content types, json is not one of them

Comment: `An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @Musa, I get the string of data in the submit_cart.php but before that I noticed html warning in that page..

Comment: Just try outputting the whole dataset `echo json_encode($return);`

Answer (score 1):

Both are wrong if you want to get the values from `$_POST`. You need to send key-value pairs to the server and then you can access them in `$_POST` by these keys.

To send everything in 1 variable, you could do something like:

```
...
var data = {json: localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart")};
...
```

Note that sending an object is always a good idea as jQuery will take care of encoding the data correctly when you use an object.

And then you can get it in php like:

```
// you only need this, no additional encoding / decoding
$data = json_decode($_POST["json"], true);
```

Comment: i get null in the php and success function

Comment: @Keren Can you post the corrected code below the original version in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already encoded as you mention in your question `console.log(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));`

output is

```
[{"name":"Banana","price":1.33,"count":5},{"name":"Apple","price":1.22,"count":5},{"name":"Shoe","price":22.33,"count":1}]
```

So in your ajax request

```
data: { json_data:data} ,
```

in this case data work as object and it is easy to fetch value.

and in php file

```
echo $_POST["json_data"];
```

Comment: but why am I not getting anything in the success function?

Comment: check your browser console for what data is sending by the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending any data to the target page here.Inside the ajax send the data with data: parameter.Then instead of using success function use .done() function outside the ajax.The done function is better in terms of result handling.You can check whether your data is transmitting or not by using the developer tool network.There all the request and response data is shown.Hopefully this will solve the problem.